# how to get the pressed key with jquery using event that fires AFTER the key is typed

Tags: jquery, keyboard

is there an alternative to onkeypress that fires **AFTER** the key is pressed .. I want to get the pressed key but onkeypress fires before the key is typed

Comment: How can anything fire before the key is pressed? o_0 I'm guessing you want `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

Comment: oh I meant "typed" .. i'll edit it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the keyup event. You can read more about this on the following link: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Example from W3-schools:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

As found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp

An alternative method would be

```
$(document).on('keyup' , '#yourElement' , function(){
 // Do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or is this what you are looking for? The keyup function fiers when you let go of the key.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function(e) {
    $('lable').text(e.keyCode);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Type in the input:
<input type="text"><br/>
Code of the pressed key: <lable></lable>
```